# Using 2 USB Microphones in SingStar

Tags: audio-hardware, singstar

I just bought a PS3 and my wife wants to get the game SingStar.

I've seen that you can buy complete packages that come with the game and the two (Red and Blue) microphones, but I already have 2 USB microphones from my Xbox 360 (for Rock Band: Beatles).  From what I've read online, the Xbox USB mics are compatible with the PS3 but they only ever mention using 1 mic.

Since the mics that come with SingStar actually only use 1 USB connection for both mics does this mean that I will be able to use the RockBand mic but only one of them or has anyone had luck with using 2 USB RockBand mics in lieu of the standard Red and Blue SingStar mics?

It would be great to only have to buy the games and not *another* piece of hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I am finding conflicting information. On [one hand](http://boardsus.playstation.com/t5/SingStar/Microphone-Compatibility-Singstar-Rockband-American-Idol/td-p/34892299)..

> As I understand it, newer Singstar titles on the PS3 (SSp3) shipped with two separate usb mics instead of the adapter,  likely the reason why these titles also accept third party or alternate usb mics.  Instead of the 2 separate mics on one usb, it is now 1 analog signal per usb input, which is how most of the other software interpreted the input.  The adapter may have made the SS mics usable on such software as well, though perhaps at reduced performance, or perhaps only in single player  mode since the other software isn't prepared to look for the player 2 input on the same usb channel, and conversely why the SSp2 titles couldn't use other mics which DIDN"T carry the second channel at all in the usb1 input.

That would also make the most sense; USB mics are all extremely standard and this would maximize compatibility and thus sales.

On the [other hand..](http://www.freak-search.com/en/thread/660116/singstar_with_usb_mics...)

> Singstar 2 arrived today and I tried it with my two Logitech USB mics.
>   It doesn't work. :( These mics work in the PS3 audio-in setup, but within Singstar it says there is no mic. It looks like I could get 'jackplug type' mics working on it if I had a Singstar USB converter. Anyway, just thought I'd point it out here in case anyone else is trying that route. From what I've read elsewhere **it seems some USB mics do work**, but not the Logitech mic that came with High School Musical for the Wii and not the other Logitech USB mic I have.

Sony is *also* the company who invented the glorious proprietary Memory Stick format (now dead, thankfully).

So, I would file this under "try at your own risk.."

Comment: Maybe not as dead as we might have hoped...  :(